# Trouble uploading a file (Express/Node, Multer)

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Hi everyone I am using jade to generate html and have this form on the page:

```
      p Upload New Schedule
      #uploadNew
        form(id = "form1", action="/upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
          input(type="file", id="control")
          br
          input(type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit")
```

when I select a file and try to upload, the connection times out.  What am I doing wrong? I am using multer middleware to help upload as well:

back in app.js:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});

...

app.post('/upload', upload.single('Submit'), function(req, res) {
    if (done == true) {
        console.log(req.files);
        res.end("File uploaded");
    }
});
```

Comment: Where are you defining `done` ? If it is never true your post will not get to the log or response.

Answer (score 0):

Add a name field to your input box of "file" type:

```
p Upload New Schedule
  #uploadNew
    form(id = "form1", action="/upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
      input(type="file" id="control" name="control")
      br
      input(type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit")
```

you have not defined "done" anywhere so i am just ignoring it.
also in **upload.single(..)** you have to pass the **name** property of the input field of **"file"** type (in this case it is "control")

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});

...

app.post('/upload', upload.single('control'), function(req, res) {

        console.log(req.files);
        res.end("File uploaded");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to gaurav gupta's answer, when using multer's `upload.single()` function for the middleware, your file will be in `req.file`, not `req.files`. `req.files` is for when you use `upload.array()` or `upload.any()`.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('control'), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.file);
  res.send("File uploaded");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste example of uploading and retrieving multiple files (one binary, one JSON) using multer...

Client side:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="binaryFileToUpload" id="binaryFileToUpload" >
    <input type="file" name="jsonFileToUpload" id="jsonFileToUpload" >
    <input type="button" value="Upload" name="submit" onclick="upload()">
</form>
<script>
upload()
{
    let fileInput = document.getElementById("file");

    var one = fileInput.files[0]; //binary
    var two = new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.someRegularObj, null, 2)], 
    {type : 'application/json'}); //JSON

    var url = "http://localhost:4000/upload"; //your URL here
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function() {
        alert('File(s) uploaded!');
    };
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);

    if (window.FormData) // Chrome
    {
        var formData = new FormData();
        //must match server's router.post('/receiveFiles', upload.array("upload", ...), ...
        formData.append("upload", one);
        formData.append("upload", two);

        xhr.send(formData);
    }
}
</script>
```

Server side (ES6 module / class):

```
defineRoutes()
{
    let upload = multer({storage: multer.memoryStorage()});

    let selector = "upload"; //must match client's formData.append() key!
    let numFiles = 2;

    router.post('/receiveFiles', upload.array(selector, numFiles),
        this.tryExtractFilesFromRequest.bind(this)
        );
}

tryExtractFilesFromRequest(req,res,next)
{
    if (req.files)
    {
        let one      = req.files[0];
        console.log(one); //instance of File, has .buffer, a binary representation

        let twoAsJsonString = Buffer.from(req.files[1].buffer, 'binary').toString('utf8');
        let two = JSON.parse(twoAsJsonString);

        res.end();
    }
}
```